# Hotkey in IntelliJ IDEA to extract all return statements in method

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For example, if we have method:

```
private A getA(A a1, A a2) {
    if (a1 != null) {
        return a1;
    } else {
        return a2;
    }
}
```

Does IDEA have some hotkey (like <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+V</kbd> for extracting variable) to make from this code something like this:

```
private A selectA(A a1, A a2) {
    A result;
    if (a1 != null) {
        result = a1;
    } else {
        result = a2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: I don't _think_ IntelliJ has a "single exit point" refactor.

Comment: There is not. If there were, it would (likely) be offered as a quick fix for the _Java > Method Metrics > Method with multiple return points_ inspection. Opening a feature request is likely your best bet.

Comment: There really is no such refactoring in IntelliJ. (In this specific case you could use the Intention "Replace 'if-else' with '?:' " (press alt-enter on the "if"). That does not help with the general case, of course. Also most of the times I prefer the "early return" to the "single return" style. I used to be a strong proponent of the "single return" style. Over the years and with lots of experience, however, I changed my opinion. Strictly enforcing "single return" often leads to worse readability due to unnecessary nesting and superfluous local variables.

Comment: Perhaps a single exit point made sense in the days of manual memory management and no try/finally (i.e. never in Java), but now it's an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Put the caret at the method name, press <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd>, then choose "Transform body to single exit-point form". It will convert the method to a single `return` form.

The setting can be found in `Settings | Editor | Intentions`, then `Java | Control flow | Transform body to single exit-point form`. It should be enabled by default.